# how to debug to find out the reason why the website doesn't get displayed on android browser

Tags: android, html, easeljs

I am doing some tests and realised that android browser does not display my website. The other browsers are ok.

I used these libraries:

- easeljs
- mathjax
- jquery

I also used html5 webworkers. This is my test website: [thewebdesign.org/v16/](http://thewebdesign.org/v16/)

My question is:How to find out the reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging to be able to inspect the chrome console.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging is the most accurate / best, as suggested above, but if you are not able to use remote debugging: You can try out browserstack (http://browserstack.com/). Even though you would fix the android issue, there are no guarantees, IOS works. That is why I have been using browserstack, to test IOS.