# Android Native/Stock/Default Browser Won't load my React Web App

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, browser

So my react web application loads perfectly fine on Android Chrome Browser, and other browsers such as UC Browser, Safari on iOS.

However, recently we found that the web application loads blank page when opened using Android Native/Stock/Default Browser ( The blue globe icon ) found on any Samsung / Lenovo devices.

I was able to use weinre / ngrok to attach web debugger, but I was not able to find any errors. The browser would just stop requesting for more static assets and stop doing anything.

I ran another test for my internal web application which is also a react web app (same config), and it loads fine on Android Native/Stock/Default Browser. I'm looking for clue as to what may cause this browser to stop requesting from the webserver...

Thx

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same problem. If you found a solution, could you share it please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to debug to find out the reason why the website doesn't get displayed on android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117069/how-to-debug-to-find-out-the-reason-why-the-website-doesnt-get-displayed-on-and)

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this issue?